# Taylor expansion at $\infty$

Tags: taylor-expansion

What does it mean to:

> Take a Taylor expansion at infinity

A taylor expansion of $\Gamma (x)$ centered at 0 gives me: $$\frac{1}{x}-\gamma +\frac{1}{12} \left(6 \gamma ^2+\pi ^2\right) x+\frac{1}{6} x^2 \left(-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma \pi ^2}{2}+\psi ^{(2)}(1)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$

But an expansion of $\Gamma (x)$ centered at $\infty$ gives me $$\left(\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}+\frac{1}{6} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}\right)\right) \exp \left(\left(-\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right) x+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)\right)$$

Comment: Change the variable to $y=1/x$ and then make the expansion around $y=0$

Comment: Obviously, neither of those are proper Taylor series, because Gamma function can't be expressed as Taylor series around those points. Which is why the leading terms are not the variable raised to positive integer powers

Comment: How did you get these particular expansions though? Wolfram Alpha? Please note that Wolfram will give you different kinds of series, not just Taylor series. It usually has a note in the corner of the output cell telling what kind of series this is

Comment: Note that the phrase "***Taylor*** series" is not a term for general series; it refers to a very specific type of series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, when one asks for a power series about $\infty$, what is usually meant is a series about $0$, chosen so that its annulus of convergence borders $\infty$.

For example, consider the function

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{2-x} $$

This has three different convergent series about $x=0$:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) x^n  \qquad \qquad |x| < 1$$
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} (-1) x^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} x^n \qquad \qquad 1 < |x| < 2$$
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} (-1)\left( 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right) x^n
\qquad \qquad 2 < |x|$$

The last of these converges in a neighborhood of $\infty$, and is most likely what people mean if they ask for a series about $\infty$ for $f$.